Build Failed in React Native. BuildConfig Symbol not found


`BUILD FAILED in 27s
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\authentication\authentication\android\app\src\main\java\com\authentication\MainApplication.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
^
symbol: variable BuildConfig
C:\authentication\authentication\android\app\src\main\java\com\authentication\MainApplication.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
^
symbol: variable BuildConfig
C:\authentication\authentication\android\app\src\main\java\com\authentication\MainApplication.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
^
symbol: variable BuildConfig
C:\authentication\authentication\android\app\src\main\java\com\authentication\MainApplication.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) { ^ symbol:   variable BuildConfig location: class MainApplication
4 errors
`FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
This is the error message.
I am not developer of this project. Previous developer went to change the project name in /java/com/ directory.

This is the error message.
I am not developer of this project. Previous developer went to change the project name in /java/com/ directory.

What version of RN are you working with? Also, please share your package.json file.

I have similar problem and turns out it is becos of the project name not aligned.
please go to file build.gradle and check check namespace & applicationId under android {}
